# Error when access the Data driven method to read multiple values

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, bdd, data-driven

> Following Problem occurs when accessing the excel method to read
>   multiple values
>   "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot
>   implicitly convert type 'string' to 'object[*,*]'"

Here is my code :

Base Method:

```
         namespace NewAutomationFramework.Helpers

         {
         class Excel
          {
          public String[,] ReadRange(int starti, int starty, int endi, int endy)
           {
           Object[,] holder = range.Value2;
           String[,] returnstring = new String[endi-starti+1,endystarty+1];
           for(int p=1; p<=endi-starti+1; p++)
             {
               for(int q=1; q<=endy-starty+1; q++)
                {
                returnstring[p-1, q-1] = holder[p, q].ToString();
                }
                }
               return returnstring;
            }
```

Class where I call the method :

```
namespace NewAutomationFramework.Steps
    {
   [Binding]
   public class ExcelWork
   {
   public void verifyExcelData()

        {
            Excel ex = new Excel(@"test2",1);

            string[,]read = ex.ReadRange(1, 1, 1, 1);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("/n",read));

            ex.close();
           }
```

> "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot
>   implicitly convert type 'string' to 'object[*,*]'"

Comment: Please, edit this question to keep it readeable. Format the code before paste it here

Comment: ya done. Hope its now in readable format